# A function that takes in both a list (myList) and a value (n) and checks whether or not the value is in that list

Tags: python

I was wondering if anyone new how to do this question in python? 
Write a function that takes in both a list (myList) and a value (n) and checks whether or not the value is in that list. If the value does exist in the list replace it with the value “1”. Your function should return the updated list. Use function signature: def replaceNum(myList, n):

Example: If the input to the function were replaceNum([12, 6, 10, 10], 10), the function would return a list with [12, 6, 1, 1].

I have this so far

```
def replaceNum(myList,n):
    new_list = []
    for i in range(0, len(myList)):
        if i == n:
            myList[n] = 1
            new_list.append(i)

        return myList[i]
print(replaceNum([5, 10, 20], 10))
```

but it only prints a 5 and I need it to print [5,1,20]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). The function iterates over each element in `myList` and replaces it with `1` if it is equal to `n`:

```
def replaceNum(myList, n):
    return [x if x != n else 1 for x in myList] 

print(replaceNum([5, 10, 20], 10))
```

**Output**

```
[5, 1, 20]
```

Comment: @ZAMUEL123 I think you need 15 reputation before you can vote

Answer (score 0):

To focus on fixing your code.

One of the main problems is that you are returning inside your loop. Not only that, but you are only returning a single item from `myList`.

Instead, what you should do is set up your for loop to iterate with your index and value using `for i, v enumerate(myList)` and then just change the value when you find a match.

Like this:

```
def replaceNum(myList,n):
    for i, v in enumerate(myList):
        if v == n:
            myList[i] = 1
    return myList
print(replaceNum([5, 10, 20], 10))
```

Then to further optimize, look at [gtlambert's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35806324/1832539) answer